# What was the name of the 80s scifi show that had ewoks?

Tags: story-identification, star-wars, ewoks

It is possible they weren't ewoks, but as a kid I identified them as being the same as ewoks..

Basic plot:

A family (husband, wife, couple of kids) crash land their spaceship on a planet. They meet friendly ewoks, but also another race of creatures which are hostile. The hostile creatures steal the power source to their spaceship, preventing them from leaving.

Most episodes were based around their unsuccessful attempts to recover their power source from the hostile creatures.

It was live action.

Comment: I have just googled for [Ewoks TV show](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Ewoks#Television). You [owe me](http://www.stufffromthe80s.co.uk/80s-tv-shows/sci-fi/ewoks) about 1/2 billion permanently damaged brain cells and the cost of 3 years of intensive psychiatric therapy.

Comment: @DVK: Then why not put it as an answer?

Comment: @TangoOversway - it wasn't live action, so it doesn't fit

Comment: As you're talking about a series, not a one-off thing, I assume you're not talking about [The Star Wars Holiday Special](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Star_Wars_Holiday_Special)?

Comment: Land of the Lost. Pakuni, not Ewoks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are 2 made-for-TV movies about Ewoks :

- [Ewoks: The Battle for Endor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ewoks%3a_The_Battle_for_Endor)
- [Caravan of Courage: An Ewok Adventure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caravan_of_Courage%3a_An_Ewok_Adventure)

*Disclaimer : Any damage to your psychological integrity after watching, reading about or even just slightly checking for information about those movies is not my responsibility.*

Comment: I must have seen both movies as a kid and thought they were a series (they both involve the same characters).

Comment: Neither of these are episodic tv shows, though.

Comment: Are these considered canon?

Comment: One of the episodic movies had the guy from [Our House](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Our_House_%281986_TV_series%29) and those commercials: [Wilford Brimley](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilford_Brimley)

Comment: Do these fit the "crash land their spaceship on a planet. They meet friendly ewoks, but also another race of creatures which are hostile. The hostile creatures steal the power source to their spaceship, preventing them from leaving."?

Comment: @Xantec - for a given value of 'canon' - Star Wars is notorious for applying levels to its canonicity. I think these movies fall somewhere above fanon and below the standard expanded universe canon (meaning officially sanctioned books and movies can override)

Comment: I knew the answer to the canonical-ism of the Ewok adventures at some point, but I can't remember for sure.  My impression of my memory is that they are not at all canon.

Comment: @DVK - That was the plot of one of the movies, but I don't recall which.  A human family crash landed on the forest moon (a la Swiss Family Robinson), the parents are killed, a little girl is saved by Wicket and, as I recall, he helped her find her older brother and the ship's power module, which had been taken by some evil creature or other.  It's a fuzzy memory that I tried to forget.  Thanks to everyone for dragging up this horrific memory.  It's almost as bad as the Star Wars Holiday Special.

Comment: @DVK From carvan of Courage: "On the forest moon of Endor, the starcruiser of the Towani family lies wrecked. The Towani family (Catarine, Jeremitt, Mace, and Cindel) are stranded."
 and 
"The Towanis decide to stay with the Ewoks until they can repair the starcruiser, and Izrina leaves to go back to her family." 
Looks pretty close to me :)

Comment: @DVK Yes, that is the first one. I remember watching these when I was little, as I loved the ewoks. The second one was much darker, and they kill off pretty much everyone from the first show in the opening scene. Don't remember the rest of that ones plot though.

Comment: [I wish it were so easy to say these aren't canon.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ewoks%3a_The_Battle_for_Endor#Alleged_continuity_issues)

Comment: These films are no longer considered canon