# Can anyone identify the movie a kid with her father stranded in an alien planet?

Tags: story-identification

I used to watch a movie, probably in the early 90's.

The movie was about a girl (blonde curly hair) with her father who crash landed on a planet. She then went out for a power source for their spaceship, and encountered with some gummy bears like aliens, those aliens communicate through whistle may be...and there was another alien who can ran fast...anyone has any idea about that movie?

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8469/what-was-the-name-of-the-80s-scifi-show-that-had-ewoks

Answer (score 13):

The movie is [Ewoks: the battle for Endor](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089110/).

Comment: +1 for getting Ewoks from _gummy bears like aliens_.

Comment: who would have ever guessed Ewoks are Gummy Bears :) +1 from me as well..