# Father and Daughter land on Alien World

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw a film nearly twenty years ago.  A father and daughter land, maybe crash, a space craft on an alien world.  When they land, they're in a forest.  The daughter was probably in her young teens.

There was a kingdom on the planet ruled by an evil humanoid man or alien with brownish skin and a very ugly face.  I think the dad was trying to repair the space craft.

I think the father and daughter wore normal earth-clothes, while the native's costumes were different.

In one scene a line of troops are marching along the side of a mountain with a cliff on one side and a rock wall on the other.  I want to say the troops were the same brown-skinned disfigured species as the king.  The mountain path was pretty arid.  The daughter was captured along with short fuzzy bear like creatures.  She and the bear creatures were either being pulled in carts or carried in a liter.  She escapes together with one of the bears.  There is a scene where the camera is inside one of the liters/carts with her and a bear and they tear a hole in the bottom of whatever is carrying them.

There was a young woman with black hair who was also high-ranking in the kingdom.  She might have been the wife of the alien ruler, but unlike him she was definitely human.  I seem to recall her arguing with the alien ruler at some point.

It might have been part of a series of films.

At the end the end of the film, the ruler of the kingdom is killed in a flash of light while chasing the daughter.  The alien either melts or is charred to a crisp, I just remember his death scaring me as a kid.

Can anyone identify this film?

Comment: Sounds rather Ewok-like.

Comment: Do you remember any other details? What cannel it was on if you watched it on TV? Was the movie released long before you watched it or did it look similar to the films you'd seen?

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8469/what-was-the-name-of-the-80s-scifi-show-that-had-ewoks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.  It was Ewoks: The Battle for Endor, 1985.

The woman with black hair is Charal, the alien leader is Terek.  The family crash landing is the Towani family, and the girl is Cindel.

Since I am pretty well acquainted with the main star wars trilogies and hadn't heard of it connected with them, I didn't suspect it was star wars.  This was a minor spin off movie.  So, Mr. Lister was correct that the bears are Ewoks.

Comment: Congrats! I did look at the synopsis for the Ewok films, but I didn't find enough matches with your description to decide if one of them was it.

Comment: Hi there! Been a while but could you self-accept that? Keeps things clean :)

Comment: @Jenayah  Always glad to give myself credit  ;)